# react invariant error did not show error on which file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have no clue where to debug seeing the error like this[image]

React did not tell which file to look for. I was playing around with this code https://github.com/atulmy/node-express-react-redux-zwitter

Comment: Go to the file which logged a few lines before. Which component uses another component in their JSX? Make sure you exported components from modules.

Comment: @AndrewLi I know what the error means but react can't tell which file to go?

Comment: No, because the error is raised by React's file. Just go through all your components.